# Deployment with Password using Linux in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

How to deploy a app with password in meteor using linux. It's deploy good when with out set password.But i need to deploy app with password in meteor. I did but gets some error messages i didn't understand the following messages.So please see the below deployment process and suggestions me what to do?

```
[root@localhost myapp]# meteor deploy myapp.meteor.com --password
deploy: the --password option needs a value.
Try 'meteor help deploy' for help.
[root@localhost myapp]# meteor deploy myapp.meteor.com 123456
deploy: too many arguments.
Usage: meteor deploy <site> [--settings settings.json] [--debug] [--delete]

Deploys the project in your current directory to Meteor's servers.

You can deploy to any available name under 'meteor.com'
without any additional configuration, for example,
'myapp.meteor.com'. If you deploy to a custom domain, such as
'myapp.mydomain.com', then you'll also need to configure your domain's
DNS records. See the Meteor docs for details.

The --settings flag can be used to pass deploy-specific information to
the application. It will be available at runtime in Meteor.settings, but only
on the server. If the object contains a key named 'public', then
Meteor.settings.public will also be available on the client. The argument
is the name of a file containing the JSON data to use. The settings will
persist across deployments until you again specify a settings file. To
unset Meteor.settings, pass an empty settings file.

The --delete flag permanently removes a deployed application, including
all of its stored data.

Options:
  --delete, -D  permanently delete this deployment
  --debug       deploy in debug mode (don't minify, etc)
  --settings    set optional data for Meteor.settings
  --star        a star (tarball) to deploy instead of the current Meteor app

[root@localhost myapp]#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should use both command and option:

```
meteor deploy myapp.meteor.com --password 123456
```